# Visual Studio TestStack.White NuGet

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I'm trying to install TestStack.White via "Manage NuGet Packages" everytime I get this error.

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Failed to initialize the PowerShell host. If your PowerShell execution policy setting is set to AllSigned, open the Package Manager Console to initialize the host first.
```

Any ideas how to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off the firewall for a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project/solution in Visual Studio, and open the console using the Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console command.  Then try again